# electrostatic potential, analytic properties

Tags: mathematical-physics, electrostatics

An electrostatic potential associated  with some delocalized  charge $\int \rho(\mathbf{r}) d{\mathbf{r}}$ is given by:

$$v_H(\mathbf{r}) = \int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}d\mathbf{r'}$$

This potential is finite at $\mathbf{r}=0$. Since $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$ is a solution to a singular Poisson's equation, we can show that:

$$\nabla^2v_H(\mathbf{r})=-4\pi\rho(\mathbf{r})$$
where $\rho$ is a smooth function being finite everywhere.

Would a function

$$v(\mathbf{r}) = \int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^n}d\mathbf{r'}$$

(where $n$ is some nonnegative integer)

be also finite at $\mathbf{r}=0$?

In this case, $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^n}$ does not represent a solution to Poisson's equation ($\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3$) and the above analysis is not valid.

Comment: Since you said yourself, it does not represent a solution to Poisson's equation, why would be interested it these functions?

Comment: I am working in the field of quantum chemistry. I would like to use a model potential like the one I am asking about in electronic structure calculations.

Comment: I don't see why this would NOT be finite at $r=0$...

Comment: Let me see if I can't make some plots for this.

Comment: Well I don't understand the meaning that the potential is finite at r = 0. But, maybe you should expand the factor $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{n}}$ and check what conditions should apply to the series to be convergent. We already know that with $n=0$ and with $n=1$, it is convergent.

Comment: I think, my question is, where is r=0? Relative to the charge distribution.

Comment: Let's assume that we are considering an atom. Then, r=0 is at the nucleus.  But does this question has anything to do with the one I am asking?

Comment: hold on, might solve to a hypergeometric. checking now with a cohort of mine. I'll post if I get anything worthwhile

Comment: wait, this might be QFT related...?

Comment: nope, the question was inspired by some problem in DFT

Comment: ok, the best ive gotten is that $r = 0$ is not finite. I found the general form of the integral, saw it could be written in beta functions. Hypergeometric, all the stuff was imaginary. This is no answer by any means, but I think not. Not confident enough in what I did to post an answer.

Comment: related (and by the same poster): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44760/potential-for-charge-distribution-finiteness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too simple, and certainly not a general solution, but anyway here goes.

The simplest case is a spherical charge distribution:

$$\rho= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \rho_0 & r \le a \\ 0 & r>a \end{array} \right. $$
Then

$$ V(0) = \rho_0 \int_0^a \frac{4 \pi r^2}{r^n} dr = 4 \pi \rho_0 \int_0^a r^{2-n} dr $$

Cases:

$$ 0<n<3 \qquad  V(0) = \frac{4 \pi \rho_0}{3-n} a^{3-n} \text{ , finite}$$

$$ n=3 \qquad  V(0) = 4 \pi \rho_0 \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \ln \left(\frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)  \rightarrow \infty $$

$$ n>3 \qquad V(0) = \frac{4 \pi \rho_0}{n-3} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-3}} - \frac{1}{a^{n-3}} \right) \rightarrow \infty $$

In all these cases, the denominator of the original integral, $|r-r'|^n$, grows without bound for large $r$, and the charge is localized around the origin, so

$$ \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} V(r) =0 $$

So, $n=3$ divides the finite from the infinite cases.  (Technically, I suppose this calc constitutes a counter-example for $n \ge 3$ by exhibiting an unbounded result for those cases).